# Querying TXT records (DNS) from app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dns

Is there a way to query the DNS for a particular a txt record given the domain name from app engine .. I looked into pydns, but then "socket" is not available on app engine ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use sockets from AppEngine; you can only use higher level interfaces (namely http/https through `urllib`).

You could use an existing website / web service such as this (queried via urllib):

http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php

But it's a bit of a kludge.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to abuse other services with automated requests without their permission. I did that at one point, and most services ended banning my app or using rate limits. Therefore it's best to run your own proxy / support services, like I currently do.

Comment: I agree.  You should always get permission if you're going to be putting a volume of requests through another site.

Answer (score 0):

DNS lookups are available using [App Engine Sockets](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/), which is now in preview mode.. This also means that eventually it will be available for everyone.

*However it's only available for paid apps...*

Comment: It doesn't support TXT lookups.